# Getting request failed 404 error on react app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, localhost

I am working on a React web app using Mongodb for my db and Express on the backend.
When running locally on Chrome, I cannot access any of the data. db is running locally. I have not changed any code since the last time it was working...

Here is the error I receive when trying to load any data on the frontend:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

This is what I'm trying to load, a page showing each place by id and its images and data:

```
axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/places/${placeID}`)
      .then((res) => {
        res.data.selectedImage = res.data.images[0];
        this.setState({ place: res.data });
        console.log({ place: res.data });      
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

My backend routes have been unchanged since the start when app was loading before:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

require("./database");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));

app.get("/places", require("./controllers/getPlaces"));
```

What am I missing here as far as looking for errors?
This is my first app, for reference.

Comment: Erro code 404 means page does not found,which mean there is no specific router pointing to the searching page. do you have  a router to '/places/:placeId' ?

Comment: yes,can you show the code of the same in your question

Comment: @sharunkk app.get("/places/:id", require("./controllers/getPlaces"))

Comment: i mean code in getPlaces.js